# void* to an anonymous structure or a long string of data, etc

Tags: c++

I'm trying to code a interpreted script to understand some concepts, and one functionality of it is to access native C++ functions that I will add a list of accessible functions (a good ol' vector).

eg. I'll declare this in my script:

```
extern double pow(double, int);
```

and this in c++

```
double pow(double, int) { /*code*/ }
/*somewhere else*/
vector<void*> accessibleFunctions;

accessibleFunctions.push_back(pow);
```

Up to here everything is ok.

The next step is to call it, and is where I'm having problems, I made a sample project to test it:

```
double custom_pow(double x, int y)
{
    if(y == 0) return 1;
    for(; y > 1; y--) x*=x;
    return x;
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    vector<void *> listOf;

    listOf.push_back(custom_pow);

    double(*func)(...);
    func = (double(*)(...))(listOf[0]);

    struct Arguments { double base; int expoent; };
    Arguments args;
    args.base = 10;
    args.expoent = 3;

    cout << func(args) << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

This code works as it is...

The data inside the struct is ordered the same way as the parameters in the method signature;

But I'm stuck thinking how I get rid of the "struct" part, as it is not dynamic... I've tried to use malloc and use the "void*" that comes out, but as it is a pointer, when I put in the place of "args" the "x" is the address, and "y" is the following address in memory.

I was wondering if there is a way to pass the data pointed by the void pointer directly in the `func(args)` part. In C# I'm pretty sure I would find a way through reflection (but I don't know if I can in C++).

I understand the security implications here (kinda...), but they are not my concern at this point, it won't become a product or solution to be used in real life.

Comment: ...not to be used in "real life".

Comment: This is a very hairy problem and can't really be handled elegantly or delicately. Look at my history of questions and maybe you'll get some guidance, but I've ended up using some inline assembly to push byte data in the expected calling convention order and executing the method from assembly. Dirty, but it technically does the job.

Comment: @WilliamCustode, Thanks I'm looking for it right now, but if you could point me to the link of the question you mentioned I would be much obliged.

Comment: I think this is relative: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20528100/call-method-without-specifying-parameters